# Правильное отображение рекламы Admob

Tags: android

Добрый день! Есть приложение в котором я показываю межстраничную рекламу. Показываю таким образом: Открывается MainActivity и загружается реклама. Затем при нажатии на кнопку сначала открывается межстраничная реклама, а когда ее закроют, то запускается SecondActivity.

Проблема в том, что если интернет слабый или реклама не успела загрузиться, то при нажатии на кнопку SecondActivity не запуститься и пользователю придется еще раз нажать на кнопку, что не очень хорошо.

Я создал метод, в котором все это происходит. Хочу спросить у вас как правильнее отображать рекламу. Например если реклама не успела загрузиться, чтобы в любом случае запустилась SecondActivity и не пришлось еще раз тыкать на кнопку?

В классе NetworkUtil происходит проверка подключения к интернету.

Вот весь код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdRequest adRequesti;
    private InterstitialAd adMob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adMob = new InterstitialAd(this);
        adMob.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(идентификатор));
        adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adMob.loadAd(adRequesti);
    }

    public void onBtn1Click(View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        showAds(intent, MainActivity.this);
    }

    private void showAds(Intent i, Context c) {
        final Intent intent = i;
        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE | NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            adMob.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
                adMob.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Повторите попытку!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    adMob.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо это:

```
if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
            adMob.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Повторите попытку!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Сделайте вот так:

```
if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
        adMob.show();
    } else {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Если интернет есть и реклама загружена - показываем  рекламу, если нет - запустим `SecondActivity`

Comment: Спасибо, что-то сразу не догадался так прописать

Answer (score 1):

1. Наличие соединения не требуется для показа уже загруженной рекламы.
2. На мобилах проверять наличие соединения - в целом бесполезное занятие, т.к. оно появляется/пропадает вплоть до 60 раз в минуту.
3. Не пускать юзера дальше по навигации из-за того, что реклама не загружена - плохая идея с точки зрения UX. Юзер не поймёт, что происходит и будет писать гневные отзывы по поводу неработающей кнопки перехода.

Советую в методе перехода к следующей активити проверить только наличие загруженной рекламы и всё. Если ест - показываем и перенаправляем дальше, если нет - не судьба и перенаправляем дальше. Так у вас и код чище будет и реклама показана будет и юзер не будет думать, что кнопка не работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Переделаю свой код с учетом вашего ответа